# mips frame pointer ($fp) global pointer

Tags: gcc, stack, mips, stack-frame

[in this C to MIPS example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q000n.png)  MIPS  frame pointer ($fp) takes one word (4 bytes ) , but what is the use of the other 4 bytes that gcc decided to allocate in  the stack frame of main function,
is it global pointer $gp thing ?

Answer (score 1):

The size of stack frames must be multiples of 8 in MIPS architecture.  It is described at p.D-20 in MIPS RISC ARCHITECTURE by Kane & Heinrich.